# Best self leveling compound to use for this situation with LVP (1/2" feather edge thickness)

Tags: slab, self-leveling-concrete, leveling

Looking for advice on which type of self leveling compound to level most of the concrete floor [tied to this question asked earlier](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/282753/adding-laminate-to-concrete-slab-am-i-planning-this-right/282771?noredirect=1#comment588878_282771).  I want to make it close to 6/16" min relative height so its not too high or low for the transition to the tile with laminate.

**Plan:**

1. Clean and Use primer on cement.
2. Add 9 bags to get the level from picture 1 to 3 (all relative heights in x/16" taken every foot) and thickness of leveling compound is shown in picture 2.
3. Use the Diamond Cup tool to finish scraping the heights that are above the level.
4. Using a feather finishing cement & trowel to finish transitions. Assuming to level to self leveling surface tension edge as well as other spots.

**Questions**

1. Is there a preferred type of self leveling to use for 1/2" to feather or close to feather if tension edge is ok
2. Is the plan good or can it be improved to properly use the leveling (probably house for life).

--Assumptions for using leveling compound--
Prefilling the 9 5 gal buckets with water per label.
Use my corded drill to cement mixer (I have a nice SDS-Max drill if they make mixing bits)
Use a Squeegee or trowel to spread and a Spiked Screeding roller.
[image]

Comment: Question 1 is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - you have 2 of 3 votes to close the question. [Edit] to remove that part and it'll probably stay open. "Any advice..." is broad, though, got something specific to ask about?

Answer (score 2):

You may be overthinking this.

Pour out your leveling compound, starting in the lowest spot.

It seeks level as the name implies.  Get a carpet rake or small garden rake, to move the compound to where it is needed.  You can also use it to move it away from where it isn't needed, or it is too thick.
You have only a few minutes so work quickly.

If the edges is a bit thick, you can feather with flooring leveler or grind it down slightly.

The LVP does not have to have a perfect surface.  If it must transverse a lip or hump that is a 1/16 or even 1/8 it can an you will not notice.

Using underlayment as recommended previously will make the transition even more unnoticable.

Comment: You feather the edges, you can wait until the self-leveler is starting to dry/solidify, and then use a finishing trowel to feather the edges.